# wpf treeview blues. I want to select an item

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I'm trying to select a TreeViewItem. Now, I have access to the containing TreeViewItem and have told it to expand so I can select its kid. If it's already expanded all is well, if it's not then I run this code:

```
EventHandler selector = new EventHandler(delegate
    {
        if (selectedDirectoryTreeItem.ItemContainerGenerator.Status == GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated)
        {
            TreeViewItem want = selectedDirectoryTreeItem.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(dirWeWantSelected) as TreeViewItem;
            if (want == null)
                return;

                want.IsSelected = true;
            // selectedDirectoryTreeItem.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged -= selector;
        }
    });
selectedDirectoryTreeItem.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged += selector;
```

So my question is, why wont it select? want is always null. I'm scouring the interwebs looking for another way of doing this but it would be cool if somebody could explain this to me

Comment: IsSelected is set to true when the user clicks the TreeViewItem automatically, I don't get what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help, I figured it out. Well it works anyway but i'm not entirely sure why it didn't before... if anyone can tell me it would be lovely... I kinda combined elements of the two responses above and then added on a little bit to make it work. For some reason, no matter what i do I cant select the TVI (TreeViewElement) if its parent wasn't already expanded, even if the parent TVI said its contents were generated and, in fact, had contents i could iterate through. My solution was thus to wait for the contents to be generated and then itrate through them and find the one i wanted. It's really weird to me that I couldn't just grab a container given its contents. Meh. My code could stand to be refactored a little bit but here it is: (works perfectly)

```
public void listItemClickClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
    {
        try
        {
            UserFile fil = (UserFile)(sender as ListBoxItem).DataContext;
            MessageBox.Show("to do: download stuff");
            return;
        }
        catch (InvalidCastException)
        {
        }
        try
        {
            dirWeWantSelected = (Directory)(sender as ListBoxItem).DataContext;
        }
        catch (InvalidCastException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("this should never happen");
        }
        selectedDirectoryTreeItem.IsExpanded = true;
        TreeViewItem want = null;
        try
        {
            want = selectedDirectoryTreeItem.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(dirWeWantSelected) as TreeViewItem;
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("weird error");
        }
        if (want != null)
        {
            want.IsSelected = true;
        }
        else
        {
            selectedDirectoryTreeItem.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged += ItemContainerGenerator_StatusChanged;
        }
    }

    void ItemContainerGenerator_StatusChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (selectedDirectoryTreeItem.ItemContainerGenerator.Status
            == System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated)
        {
            selectedDirectoryTreeItem.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged
                -= ItemContainerGenerator_StatusChanged;
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Input,
                new Action(DelayedAction));
        }
    }

    void DelayedAction()
    {
        selectedDirectoryTreeItem.Items.MoveCurrentToFirst();
        Directory curr;
        do
        {
            curr = (Directory)selectedDirectoryTreeItem.Items.CurrentItem;
            if (curr.id == dirWeWantSelected.id)
            {
                curr.Selected = true;
                return;
            }
            selectedDirectoryTreeItem.Items.MoveCurrentToNext();
        }
        while (selectedDirectoryTreeItem.Items.CurrentItem != null);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I've personally always found it easiest to stick a Selected property into my model object and then just bind the TreeViewItem Selected property to the Selected property of the model.  Here is some code:

Model

```
public class Data : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Data()
    {
        DataItems = new List<Data>();
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    private bool _selected;
    public bool Selected
    {
        get { return _selected; }
        set
        {
            _selected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Selected");
        }
    }

    public List<Data> DataItems { get; set; }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MyControls;assembly=MyControls"
    Title="Window1">  
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="CustomTreeViewItem" TargetType="TreeViewItem">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=Selected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <DockPanel Background="Transparent">   
        <TreeView x:Name="_tvTest" DockPanel.Dock="Left" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource CustomTreeViewItem}" Width="300" >
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Data}" ItemsSource="{Binding DataItems}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Padding="2" />
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Padding="2" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>

        <Button Content="Select Random TreeView Item" Click="Button_Click" Height="50" Width="200" />
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Code behind

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    private Random _random;
    private List<Data> _dataItems;

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _dataItems = Init();
        _tvTest.ItemsSource = _dataItems;
        _random = new Random(5);
    }

    private List<Data> Init()
    {
        List<Data> dataItems = new List<Data>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            Data d1 = new Data();
            d1.Name = "Data:" + i.ToString();
            for (int j = 1; j <= 4; j++)
            {
                Data d2 = new Data();
                d2.Name = "Data:" + i.ToString() + j.ToString();
                d1.DataItems.Add(d2);
            }
            dataItems.Add(d1);
        }
        return dataItems;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = _random.Next(0, 9);
        int subIndex = _random.Next(0, 3);

        if (subIndex == 0)
            _dataItems[index].Selected = true;
        else
            _dataItems[index].DataItems[subIndex - 1].Selected = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont want everything to be expanded automatically at startup though. I know that the parent TreeViewItem is and i know the object that is bound to the TreeViewItem i want selected. I need it to work whether stuff is already expanded or not. Taking out the isExpanded setter property seems to beak it

Comment: Removing the isExpanded setter doesn't affect anything.  Not sure why you think removing it breaks anything.  You can create an Expanded property in your model and treat it exactly like the Selected property to control what's expanded.

Comment: The internals of a TVI are loaded asynchronously, as such, expanding a TVI and looking inside it immediatly doesn't work. Your code makes everything start off as expanded which just wont do. I need to expand the necessary TVI, wait for its contents to be generated, and then select TVI from inside it. Getting rid of isExpanded breaks it because your code doesn't worry about waiting for the contents to be generated. Try it yourself. Or check out Adam's answer, he was more on the right track

Comment: I cut and pasted the code from visual studio... it works fine for me, expanded or not expanded.  Glad you found your answer though.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this is a bug in WPF, but I have run into the same issue several times. I never trust the ItemContainerGenerator's Status and instead loop on separate thread as such:

```
private void _selectTreeViewHelper(object directory) {
    TreeViewItem want = null;
    bool broke = false;  //probably some sort of wait timeout instead, but works for sake of example
    while (true) {
       Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(delegate {
          want = selectedDirectoryTreeItem.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(directory) as TreeViewItem;
          if (want != null && want.IsLoaded) {
               want.IsSelected = true;
               broke = true;
          }
       }));
       if (broke) { break; }
       Thread.Sleep(100); 
    }
}
```

Then call it:

```
var thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(_selectTreeViewHelper));
thread.Start(dirWeWantSelected);
```

Pain I know, but it works.

Comment: You should look into doing things the MVVM way. mdm20's answer shows an example of using a WPF treeview using the MVVM pattern.

Comment: I was looking to answer the question of the ItemContainerGenerator, while the MVVM approach is the better way of handling this particular scenario, it is not always 100% applicable.  I've run into many situations where I need to access the actual control, and I can't simply bind to a backing model.